# Issues with js code running before page load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to defer execution of an ajax call until every single element on the page is fully rendered and all content from the initial request is downloaded.

I am fully aware of

```
$(function() { //DOM ready });
```

I have tried the window.loading event also with no luck

```
$(window).load(function(){//page fully loaded});
```

From my understanding the window.load event should only fire after all content is finished downloading; however, in my network tab I see my ajax call coming way before all requests are finished. As such the callback from my ajax call works intermittently. Sometimes I get no notifications, sometimes I get all, sometimes I get one. Setting my ajax call in a `setTimeout()` with a long wait time always works. (This is clunky and unpredictable)

The purpose of my ajax call is to trigger a call to the server, run a query on the db, and use websockets to update the UI with any notifications the user may have pending.

**My question is: Is there a better way to make sure my ajax runs only when everything is finished loading on my page?**

*Edit*
The reason this whole thing isn't working is because the html elements required to show a notifications badge are not always available when my websocket triggers the UI jquery code.

Ajax => Server code (Web socket) => [Affected html is not always available at this step] Trigger Js on client (Update UI)

Comment: Could you please post simple example of the not-working environment?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) { }) ? This will be the DOM being ready, but images don't necessarily load if they are not visible, this behaviour might vary from browser to browser..